# Complex Doctrine Entities With Predefined and Userdefined Options

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Sorry if the title is useless, having trouble thinking of what to call the issue.  I'm looking for a way to structure my Doctrine Entities.  I'm trying to write a D&D Character Sheet program for me and my friends, what I'm struggling with currently is known Languages.

Characters have known languages.

Characters have a race which generally defines a single known language for the character.

Characters have backgrounds which generally give the option to learn a number of additional languages.

Is there a decent way to have Doctrine handle these relationships?  I would prefer to have the individual languages stored as their own Entities.

So:

Character Sheet Entity

- Total list of known Languages
- Race Entity

  - Has predefined known language.
- Background Entity

  - Has a variable amount of user chosen languages.

What I was thinking is a LanguageModifier class that they can extend, which would allow flexibility later if other things need to modify what languages are known as well, I'm just having trouble visualizing the relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so what I was looking for was Override Field Association Mapping: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html

So I went with a trait that entities can use to declare they're going to modify the characters languages:

```
...

trait CharacterLanguageModifier
{
    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $isCharacterLanguageModifier = true;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CharacterLanguage")
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    protected $definedLanguages;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=8)
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $numUndefinedLanguages;

...
```

And then in the CharacterRace Entity, using the AssociationOverride to make sure it gets it's own unique table:

```
 ...

 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\AssociationOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AssociationOverride(name="definedLanguages",
 *          joinTable=@ORM\JoinTable(
 *              name="character_race_languages_defined"
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 */
class CharacterRace
{
    use CharacterAttributeModifier,
        CharacterLanguageModifier;

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad for Stack Overflow ;)

Yes you can define those relationship in doctrine.

I would use a Language entity.

```
Race <--> Language (default language(s) of race)
Background <--> languages (default languages of background)
```

You can have a getLanguages which get languages of both those relations and merge them in a single array.

Or you can add a relationship

```
Character <--> Languages (mastered languages)
```

Which allows you to add/delete languages for more customization. In this case, When you add a Race/Background, it will simply add their default language to the language collection of the character.